# Java Swing: How can I get the previous value and the current value when editing a cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I have a table that contains data from mysql. I want to modify this data when I select any row and then the modification is done to the database.

[image: able image in the link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [TableCellListener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) to identify when an actual change in the cell data occurs, allowing you to retrieve the current value of the cell (the new value) using `tcl.getNewValue()`, as well as the old one using `tcl.getOldValue()`. Additionally, it allows you to get the `row` and `column` indices of the cell that has been modified.

Example as given in the source above:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
        System.out.println("Row   : " + tcl.getRow());
        System.out.println("Column: " + tcl.getColumn());
        System.out.println("Old   : " + tcl.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("New   : " + tcl.getNewValue());
    }
};

TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(table, action);  // where table is the instance of your JTable
```

Comment: -Chris
Thank you Chris..
 But I want this modification to be done when I press the update button.

Comment: @MuhammadSalem If you mean the modification should take place in the database once you press the button, all you have to do is to save any changes occured in a `List` (using instances of a custom object for example) and execute them only if the user clicks on the "Update" button.

Comment: Thanks a lot..
The problem has been resolved and the desired results are obtained.